# Getting rid of startup background on macos Big Sur

Tags: macos

I have Macos Big Sur. The **startup screen** background is so incredibly awful, it's offensive that Apple thinks they can throw crap like that into Big Sur and then snub their noses at their users.

I found the .heic file for it, I've disabled SIP so I can replace it. I'm in a 'sudo bash' shell. But still the system tells me it is a read-only file system and I can't touch it. I tried chmod, but chmod can't get past the r/o file system either, it's not just the file.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get around the R/O problem.

The file is located at /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Big Sur Graphic.heic

And to save a few replies: Yes, I know that disabling SIP increases risk, etc etc.

Thanks!

Comment: With Big Sur it's not as simple as just disabling SIP, you also have to re-bless the snapshot if you touch it, or else;) See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur

Comment: Anyone remember when you could hack _anything_ on your Mac with ResEdit?

Comment: @jimtut - and Conflict Catcher was the single most important Utility ;)